# Does a DFS produce a MST for an unweighted directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm getting confused from reading online posts. I know that a BFS traversal on an unweighted directed graph will produce a minimum spanning tree and shortest path. Can a DFS traversal on an unweighted directed graph do the same?

Comment: BFS does not produce MST on directed graph only for undirected, DFS can do this too

Comment: @Photon really?

Comment: No, but IDS should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, Breadth-First and Depth-First both yield spanning trees. It doesn't make much sense to discuss "**minimum** spanning tree" for an unweighted graph, because all spanning trees on a given graph with n vertices have the same number of vertices (n) and the same number of edges (n-1).

**No**, Depth-First does not guarantee shortest path. You really need Breadth-First for that. Consider a cyclic graph:

```
a - h - g - f
|           |
b - c - d - e
```

Starting from vertex a, there are two possible results to depth-first search: a->b->c->d->e->f->g->h, and a->h->g->f->e->d->c->b. The former returns a very long path from a to h, and the latter returns a very long path from a to b.

Note that in this example, the graph is undirected. But undirected graphs are a special case of directed graphs; you can replace every undirected edge by two directed edges in opposing directions.